# javascript function Declaration (the diffrence beween this.method and method?)

Tags: javascript

i make function but cc method is not a function
What is diffrence between b.aa() and b.cc()?

```
function A(){
    this.aa=function(){
        console.log('11111');
    };
    cc=function(){
        console.log('2222');
    };
};
var b= new A();
b.aa();
b.cc();
```

Comment: You're declaring an implicit global variable, not a property of this. That's all. Please start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object prototyping function all variables are part of the function, so it only exists inside the function. While `this` refers to the created object:

```
function a(){
a=0;
//part of the function
this.a=1;
//part of the object
}
alert(new a(););
//will alert Object{a:1}
```